# allow to click element once per user

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple vote system (*just for fun*) where user can upvote dynamically generate posts.
I use ajax to send information to DB (post_id, user_id and depending on clicked element - upvote or downvote). But now I have a problem with limiting vote action once per user (per post).

Currently the situation is this: 1) if I log in with user A and vote - i can't vote anymore 2) after that if I log in with user B - i can vote on posts without restrictions.

Here is how I'm trying to get info if the user voted or not:

```
<?php  
    include_once 'db.php';
    $usr = $_SESSION['u_id'];//user id
    $thr_id = $row['id'];//specific post id
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `thread_upvotes` WHERE thread_id = :t_id AND upvoter_id = :u_id");
    $query->execute(array(":t_id" => $thr_id, ":u_id" => $usr));
    $fetchUpv = $query->fetchColumn();
?>
```

```
if($fetchUpv > 0) {                                                                                              
     echo "A"; //just to test if restriction is working                                                                                                                                                
} else {
     echo "<i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-up val_1'></i>";
     echo "<i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-down val_-1'></i>";
}
```

I know it's something obvious that I'm missing, but I'm not really sure exactly where.

Comment: Seems like a similiar application is being developed by [Ahmet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16936896/ahmet) maybe you should get together and help each other :)

Comment: What have you done so far to debug this? Have you verified the user ID in the session is correct? Have you verified your database table actually contains the proper records to provoke the case you are trying to test?

Comment: And FYI, a system that only doesn't output the links/buttons I would normally use to vote, has not actually _prevented_ me from using a second time. You need to perform this check at the point where the data gets inserted into the database.

Comment: Yes, I've verified user ID - if log in with different user - id is different. And yes, db includes correct data too(user id's, post id's).

Comment: I was thinking about adding restriction at the point where is data is being inserted too. But still my main point is to hide vote buttons if user upvoted specific post (and that's where i don't know if I'm doing things correctly).

Comment: you need to add a new row if the user votes which has post_id, user_id, voted [-1, 0 or 1] etc, and get the row when you get the thread/s rows, then you would know the state of the vote, there is no COUNTing involved

Comment: Yes, I could just get the row instead of the count, but the problem is still the same (checking row instead of count doesn't really change anything). Could this checking be affected by `foreach` loop? (that's how I generate posts and there's where I put the condition to check if the user voted or not).